# Is it possible to communicate between workload with envoy proxy and another workload without envoy proxy in the same namespace?

Tags: istio, istio-sidecar

I'm a newer of istio.

As like title, i deployed a pod injected envoy sidecar and a pod without envoy in the same namespace.
when i try to access from a pod without envoy to a pod with enovy, it is nothing progressed as like being blocked.

To access a workload having enovy, it must have enovy proxy? or is there other way to be able to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Pods without Istio/Sidecar should be able to access pods in the mesh by default. However, if strict mTLS is activated, they are not.

> By default, the sidecar will be configured to accept both mTLS and non-mTLS traffic, known as PERMISSIVE mode. The mode can alternatively be configured to STRICT, where traffic must be mTLS, or DISABLE, where traffic must be plaintext.

https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/tls-configuration/

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'll refer to it.